# BASH: sort email address list by domain

Tags: bash, list, dns, email-address

I would like to sort an email address list in a file by domain in bash.

```
$ cat file.txt
abc@abc.net
bbb@aaa.org
aba@aaa.com
aaa@aaa.com
ccc@abb.com
aba@abb.com
abc@abc.com
```

I tried with sort but it sorts only beginning with the username.

```
$ sort file.txt
aaa@aaa.com
aba@aaa.com
aba@abb.com
abc@abc.com
abc@abc.net
bbb@aaa.org
ccc@abb.com
```

I would like to sort first domain then username.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ sort -t @ -k2 file
aaa@aaa.com
aba@aaa.com
bbb@aaa.org
aba@abb.com
ccc@abb.com
abc@abc.com
abc@abc.net
```

`man sort`:

```
-t, --field-separator=SEP
       use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

-k, --key=KEYDEF
       sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
```